# Detecting positive solutions to an underdetermined linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, positivity

Given an m by n matrix A with real entries, how can I determine if there exists a solution to the linear equation Ax=0 whose coordinates are all strictly positive?

I am also interested in the variant of this problem that only requires that the solution's coordinates be nonnegative (and, of course, not all zero). In this case Farkas's lemma applies, but I don't know if it is of any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60104/existence-of-nonnegative-solutions-to-an-underdetermined-system-of-linear-equati?rq=1

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_variable